# Como desabilitar o evento do botão direito do mouse no Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-7, event-listener

Estou tentando desabilitar aquele menu que aparece na página quando o usuário clica com o botão direito do mouse.

No Angular, eu consigo pegar o evento de click usando `(click)="onRightClick($event)`, mas eu pego apenas o "Left Click" no `$event`.

Lembrando que se eu fizer `HostListener('click') myClick(){ }` é a mesma coisa que `(click)="myClick()`

Pesquisei na documentação do Angular e do *@HostListener* e não encontrei uma solução.

Link da documentação do @HostListener: [Angular - HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

Esse é o código onde pego o evento do click, mas ele pega apenas o Left Click, quando é o Right Click, o código não é acionado.

```js
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `(click)` assim como o parametro `'click'` em `@HostListener` irão executar como `addEventListner`, o evento click funciona mesmo somente com o click esquerdo, se deseja fazer mais iterações com o mouse deve usar `mousedown`, exemplo:

```
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
teste(event: MouseEvent)
{
    switch (event.button) {
        case 1:
            console.log('Botão esquerdo do mouse! ');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Botão direito do mouse! ');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Outro botão de mouse (click no scroll, mouse gamer, etc)');
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o seu código funcionou, só preciso de uma forma de cancelar o evento. Seja executando a ação de novo, seja, ocultando o menu que abre ao clicar com o botão direito... enfim, se tiver algum comando para tratar esse evento, é bem vindo.

Comment: @EdwardRamos seria dentro do método o `teste(event: MouseEvent)
{ event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, só que quando uso `event.preventDefault();` , nada acontece. Parece que esse método não funciona.

Comment: @EdwardRamos quer cancelar qual evento?

Comment: Cancelar o evento do botão direito, pois o preventDefaulr() não está funcionando. Eu resolvi esconder o Body quando esse evento for acionado, foi a forma mais simples de resolver isso, mas os usuários vão acabar reclamando que a página "some", enfim, é o que dá pra fazer até aqui. Vou marcar como valida a sua resposta, pois foi a que mais me ajudou a chegar no objetivo.

Comment: @EdwardRamos não imaginei que o objetivo era bloquear o menu de contexto, no caso se for isso experimente assim `@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])` e pode experimentar também: `(contextmenu)="teste($event)"` e na classe aplique o preventDefault: `teste(event) { event.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: Olha, funcionou! @GuilhermeNascimento muito obrigado pela ajuda!